# how to remove . and .. from filenames (but leave symlinks)

Tags: c++, path

I have an application that deals with files, and some files refer to other ones. Then I have to create relative paths, and also know whether a file has already been processed.

I want to 'canonicalize' the filename, removing references to '.' and '..', but keeping symbolic links, so realpath() and boost::filesystem::canonical() do not fit, as they remove also symbolic links, and I want to keep their structure.

I have coded some functions, but they are complicated, not perfect, and only work on POSIX. I wanted to know a more standard way of doing that.

Comment: I understand. But I think there is a consistent way for normalize to behave: the same one that would be done when on the shell and doing cd x/y/z; cd ..; cd t; etc.

Comment: To @abligh it may be related to C. If there is code that does the conversion it may be helpful even if written in C. It mentions boost but isn't exclusive.

Comment: What the shell does depends on the state of the `set -o physical` option.